# why yarn shows mapreduce job has finished while still fetching hive data

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, hive, apache-kafka-connect

I want to move data from hive to kafka,so i use jdbcSourceConnector to do that. the connector config like:

```
{"name": "hive_test",
 "config": {
 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
 "connection.url": "jdbc:hive2://hive_host:10000;hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false",
 "topic.prefix": "TEST",
 "poll.interval.ms": "86400000",
 "mode": "bulk",
 "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
 "query": "select * where table"
}}
```

I notice that, the connector spend about 2hour to fetch all data from hive to kafka, and yarn shows hive job was finished in about 5minutes. I have no idead what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC `select` query can finish fast (also, you should use Tez UI for Hive queries, rather than YARN / Mapreduce). Then data exists in-memory for Kafka Producer to iterate over... Check heap space of your Connector process to see if this is changing much, or a heap dump to see what records are in memory.

Ideally, you should use SparkSQL for this rather than Kafka Connect w/ JDBC. Mainly - `bulk` mode will constantly run the same select statement over your entire table, which would be very large dataset in Kafka for a typical Hive table

Comment: I think records are not in-memory，cause the data set is very large（hundreds of GBs），it will lead to OOM。 I use connector is mainly to move data from hive to kafka，the hive/hadoop cluster is not ours，so we need to operate data in our kafka cluster

Comment: The jdbc resultset is in memory. But it's a cursor, rather than a collection. It pulls chunks into memory. If you have hundreds of GB, it'll take hours to days to iterate the whole table... Besides, that's still not preventing you from using Tez with jdbc, or Spark instead